# Query search # going up in ascending order rather then fetching the actual code from database

Tags: php

I have a query fetching product ID from the database, then base on the ID #, I have a switch statement that gets the image for the product. All works fine and at the end of the switch I have a default case where it would just print out an image that says "no image available".

Here is part of the code for imagequery.php

```
<?php
if($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imagequery))
{
  switch($image['product_code'])
  {
case 0:
  echo '<th><img src="Images/pencil.jpg">';
  break;
case 1:
  echo '<th><img src="Images/pen.jpg">';
  break;
case 2:
  echo '<th><img src="Images/marker.png">';
  break;
case 3:
  echo '<th><img src="Images/clipper.png">';
  break;
case 4:
  echo '<th><img src="Images/paper.png">';
  break;
default:
  echo '<th><img src="Images/noimage.jpg">';
  break;
  }
}
```

Edit1: After doing more recommended echo checks, turns out the $image['imagequery'] is going in ascending order and I'm not sure why. My code to get $imagequery is this.

```
    $results = "SELECT product_code FROM products WHERE product_desc='Office Materials'";
    $imagequery = mysqli_query($mysqli, $results);
    include('imagequery.php');
```

Comment: I just ran your code here using various dummy values for $image['product_code'] and it does work as expected. Your problem probably lies elsewhere. Are you sure $image['product_code'] has the value you think it has at that point in the code?

Comment: The switch command works, so $imagequery is probably incorrect.  adding some extra echo statements like  `echo '<!-- ' .  $imagequery . ' -->';`should tell you more.

Comment: Yes, I just did that and turns out I was wrong. It is echoing numbers in ascending order it id does before and I thought it was fixed, I don't really understand why. I'll edit the question and include the codes for $imagequery

Comment: your query has no sort order specified. add `order by product_code`